# Problam with withInput() method when i use ajax in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, ajax, validation, laravel-5.1

I use ajax for sotre data in laravel 5.1
I have controller like this

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->input(), [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return view('common.adminwizard.technicianajax')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
}
```

When i use withInput() method ajax response

```
Internal Server Error
```

But when i remove this method ajax work correctly
and not pass data
ajax script

```
$(document).on("click", "#test-submit-btn", function() {
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/test',
    data:$("#test_form").serialize(),
    success: function(result){
    $('#test_ajax_div').html(result);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
}
})
```

Comment: Why do you use `withinput()` if you use ajax? The inputs don't change.

Comment: Becuse i create form in ajax  . when i use ajax form create again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this code

```
     public function store(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->input(), [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return view('common.adminwizard.technicianajax')->withErrors($validator)->with(['request'=>$request]);

    }
}
```